# Python crashed with OpenCV in MacOS Mojave

Tags: python, macos, opencv, macos-mojave

My OpenCV program is broken soon after I upgraded my MacBook to MacOS Mojave.

Installed the below combinations and nothing seem to work.

`Python 3.6.5 with OpenCV 3.4.1`

`Python 3.7.0 with OpenCV 3.4.3`

Simple test program

```
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = vid.read()

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Part of the Crash Log (Full log click [here](https://gist.github.com/rexlow/83279ddd88b1c3ef0fddc3df98ecfaab))

```
Process:               Python [23472]
Path:                  /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier:            Python
Version:               3.7.0 (3.7.0)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        zsh [22997]
Responsible:           Python [23472]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-10-09 14:39:32.725 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14 (18A391)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        D946F646-E90A-A450-14FB-63EA96A4C90E


Time Awake Since Boot: 18000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        3  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace TCC, Code 0x0
```

Comment: The crashing thread has `__CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__` in the backtrace.

Comment: The solution is to use an app that has the correct permissions to run the script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52655013/463796

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the suggestion from @w-m, apparently, the latest macOS variant has instilled a tight security layer on top of all apps.

Now I can invoke the camera if and only if I used the native Terminal app. Hopefully, iTerm will roll out an update soon.

Cheers!

**Update (6/11/2018)**: iTerm has released an update that will ask for camera permission.